# Summernote + Knockoutjs editor not updated after update value of observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, summernote

I have knockoutjs custom binding for summernote like this :

```
<script>
        ko.bindingHandlers.summernote = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
                var $element = $(element);
                $element.html(value).summernote({
                    onChange: function (contents) {
                        valueAccessor()(contents);
                    }
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var $element = $(element);
                $element.summernote('code',ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));

            }
        };
    </script>

<div class="html-editor" data-bind="summernote: PublishNote"></div>

self.PublishNote = ko.observable();
```

anything works fine, but not for update observable value from js.
if I init `self.PublishNote = ko.observable('Hello');`. but if I update observable variable to be `self.PublishNote('<h1>Hello World</h1')`. The Editor not updated.

Please help us finish this ko-summernote
so it can update editor from js code like this
`self.PublishNote('<h1>Hello World</h1')`

```
var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Id = '1';
            self.PublishNote = ko.observable('initial value');
            setTimeout(function(){
              self.PublishNote('<h1>Hello World</h1'); //not work
            }, 1000);

            self.Submit = function () {
                var dataToSend = {
                    PublishNote: self.PublishNote())
                };
                $.post('@Url.Action("Edit")', dataToSend)
                .success(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }

            self.Init = function () {
                $.post('@Url.Action("InitEdit")', {
                    id: self.Id
                })
                .success(function (res) {
                    self.PublishNote(res); //not work
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
        }
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
        vm.Init();

<div class="html-editor" data-bind="summernote: PublishNote"></div>
```

Comment: The binding appears to work correctly. Can you show the code where you try executing self.PublishNote('<h1>Hello World</h1')? See this example fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/sj3ptfe1/

Comment: i've updated with code
thanks

Comment: do i need add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js?

Comment: No it should work without the mapping library your code doesn't seem to use it. I just add it by default to all my projects.

Comment: Okay iam sorry finally i found the Problem after read all your fiddle. the problem is i use summernote 0.6. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Usually the custom binding uses as a parameter the configuration option for initializing the encapsulated plugin (summernote in this case).

In the example the argument allBindingsAccessor is used to get the configuration object for summernote which sets the height as 300px (simply use true if no custom config is needed). A callback is registered on the 'summernote.change' event. This callback uses the allBindings argument to access the observable used in the 'value' binding and updates its value.

This way you can turn on/off the binding by removing the binding if needed and the value observable will still be working. You can check the current value in the observable by clicking the button at the bottom of the editor.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.summernote = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        // initialize summernote with config from binding
        var summernoteConfig = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.summernote);
        summernoteConfig = (typeof summernoteConfig === 'object') ? summernoteConfig : {}
        $(element).summernote(summernoteConfig);
        $(element).summernote('code', allBindings.value());

        // callback to update value observable
        $(element).on('summernote.change',  function(we, contents, $editable) {
            allBindings.value(contents);
        });
    }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this; 

    self.PublishNote = ko.observable("INITIAL CONTENTS");
    self.ShowContents = function() {
        alert(self.PublishNote());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>

<!-- knockout -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="html-editor" data-bind="value: PublishNote, summernote: { height: 300 }"></div>
<button data-bind="click: ShowContents">Show Contents</button>
```